# Confidence interval for the parameter of a random variable

Tags: self-study, bayesian

I am studying statistics, and I came across a problem that I am not sure if what I am doing is correct or if there is some other way to do this. Any feedback is appreciated.
I divided in 2 problems, first for clarity, and second because the if there is something wrong in problem 1, than problem 2 is also wrong.

**Problem 1**
I have a family of random variables $\{X(\theta) \, | \, \theta \in \Theta\}$ ($\Theta$ is actually one dimensional) and I have one observation $x$ from $X$. I am interested in determining some confidence interval for the parameters that could have generated this observation. Then I guess I am looking for is the posterior distribution $f_{\Theta|X=x}$.
To calculate it I would use Bayes Theorem:
$$ f_{\Theta|X=x}(\theta) = \frac{f_{X|\Theta=\theta}(x) f_{\Theta}(\theta)}{\int f_{X|\Theta=\alpha}(x) f_{\Theta}(\alpha) d\alpha} $$
For this I would need the distribution of the prior, which I don't have, so I thought of just using an uninformative prior (an uniform distribution over some interval).

**Problem 2**
The problem is the same, but instead of an observation $x$, we have a measurement of it, which has associated error. We model this measurement as a normal distribution $N = N(\mu, \sigma)$ with known parameters. So now we dot not have an observation, but only the distribution of the values of the observation.
Now I want to to the same thing as in problem 1, but with this r.v. as an observation. What I thought is that in order to calculate $f_{\Theta|X=N}$ (is this notation ok?), we would need to integrate the pervious formula over $N$:
$$ f_{\Theta|X=N}(\theta) = \int f_N(x) f_{\Theta|X=x}(\theta)  dx = \int \frac{f_N(x) f_{X|\Theta=\theta}(x) f_{\Theta}(\theta)}{\int f_{X|\Theta=\alpha}(x) f_{\Theta}(\alpha) d\alpha} dx $$

Comment: Confidence intervals are not really a Bayesian concept.  You seem to want the posterior distribution, from which you might produce a [credible interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credible_interval) later.  Your notation for $N$ is also a little confusing as its relationship to X.

Comment: Let's use $y$ for the observation of $Y \sim \mathcal N(X +\mu,\sigma^2)$ so $Y$ is only related to $\Theta$ through $X$.  I would have thought you might want something like $$\frac{\int_x f_{Y|X=x}(y) f_{X|\Theta=\theta}(x) f_{\Theta}(\theta) \,dx}{\int_\alpha \int_x f_{Y|X=x}(y) f_{X|\Theta=\alpha}(x) f_{\Theta}(\alpha) \,dx\,d\alpha}$$ for the posterior distribution of $\Theta$ given the observation $Y=y$.

Comment: Of course, that makes perfect sense. The only thing is that I would model $Y$ as $\mathcal{N}(X,\sigma^2)$, so on average we measure correctly, but it does not change the idea.

Comment: Fine - I was not clear about what your original "$N=N(μ,σ)$ with known parameters" was trying to say precisely - but as you say, this detail does not really matter